# How temperature anomaly are measured

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change, temperature, measurements

Temperature Anomaly is the measure used to show that the earth is warming. [The formula for temperature anomaly](http://ete.cet.edu/gcc/?/globaltemp_anomalies/) involves in the subtraction of average temperature measurement over 30 years considered as a base line temperature . Usually temperature anomaly graphs starts from 1880, was the average taken from 1850 or which 30 years was used in the baseline or average temperature calculation?

can you suggest places that i can learn about these and get these data?

even though subtracting the baseline temperature reduces the influence of errors in measurement, still how are these error accounted for in these graphs? even modern thermometer have +/- 0.5 deg error how are these error removed from the dataset?

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked. Can you define the formula that you read elsewhere ?

Comment: meteorologic equipment are way more accurate than your home thermometer and they are calibrated often and the readings are not of only one thermometer at each station.

Comment: i am new to this field, i found the formula in this website [http://ete.cet.edu/gcc/?/globaltemp_anomalies/]

Comment: @trondhansen instruments now a days can be accurate. but in 1880's i don't think they were very precise. and i don't think they had meteorologic around the planet to measure its average temperature.

Comment: @gansub thanks for your interest in helping me. i am interested in knowing data collection and error reduction methods for temperature measurement  in the data pre-satellite era. thanks.

Comment: Data sources: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 Error issues: if we assume the error follows any sort of zero-mean distribution, adding the errors would follow the normal distribution with a zero-mean and small standard deviation (Central Limit Theorem)

Comment: @BarryCarter we were able to reduce systematic error by taking multiple samples and averaging, assuming that error have zero-mean distribution. what about error due to least count of thermometers? https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/global-temperature/ in the graph when x-axis is 1880, temperature is measured at 0.01 dec C scale. do you have any information regarding the least count of thermometers in 1880?

Comment: I actually agree with you, to some extent. See https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9675/is-non-randomly-sampled-historical-data-representative and the answers for possible further explanation.